# How to take a backup in secondary server of mongodb

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have a mongo's primary server and mongo's secondary server.

I want to take a backup mongo in secondary server in 1 time an hour.

I just wrote a simple bash script in secondary server:

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db databasename --out /root/backupdatabasename --oplog
```

When I run this script. Geting error:

```
2016-02-15T07:42:46.713+0000    Failed: bad option: --oplog mode only supported on full dumps
```

As I know: --oplog is an options point-in-time backup.

Please give me advises if I run above script without --oplog

it works fine without --oplog option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the database parameter, the command will dump all databases and include the oplog entries created since the backup started.

The oplog is stored per-mongod instance, rather than per-database, so it kind-of makes sense that you can't request the oplog for a single database.

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --out /root/backupdatabasename --oplog
```